# Making a grid with curses from a dictionary of flat tuples

Tags: python

OK, I've been trying to figure out the best way to do this for a little while and it's just not coming to me. I have a dictionary with points on a grid...

```
{(0,0):...(0,1):...}
```

I'd like to visualize this dictionary using `addch` in `curses`.

The points in the dictionary, to be printed on the screen, have to be converted like this:

```
x, y
0,0 => 1,1
1,0 => 3,1
2,0 => 5,1
3,0 => 7,1

0,0 => 1,1
0,1 => 1,3
0,2 => 1,5
0,3 => 1,7
```

[image]

I cannot think of an elegant way to take `(0,3)` and make it into `(1,7)` (the center on the screen grid).

Comment: Could you post the actual dictionary that that grid represents?

Comment: @DavidRobinson Sure, but I'm not sure how it will help. `{(0,0): [True,True,True,True], (0,1):[True,True,True,True]}` It's a maze, basically, The `True`'s represent whether or not a wall exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the conversion is just

```
x1 = 2 * x_0 + 1
y1 = 2 * y_0 + 1
```

Thus, if you want to convert the dictionary this way, you could just do:

```
new_dict = {(2 * x + 1, 2 * y + 1): v for (x, y), v in d.items()}
```

For example:

```
d = {(1, 3): 12, (7, 1): 90, (3, 1): 8, (1, 5): 15, (5, 1): 40, (1, 1): 1}
new_dict = {(2 * x + 1, 2 * y + 1): v for (x, y), v in d.items()}
print new_dict
# {(1, 3): 12, (7, 1): 90, (3, 1): 8, (1, 5): 15, (5, 1): 40, (1, 1): 1}
```